# What does the phrase "mining resources" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Here is a sentence from a space action game:

> When you are away from the battlefield, you can send your co-soldiers
>   to cleared areas, while mining resources and upgrading your equipments
>   and base.

I know the lexical meaning of the word ["mine"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mine), but they don't seem to fit here.

Comment: Does the original quotation say "equipments"?   If so, this is an error -- It should say "equipment".

Answer (score 2):

Mining is being used as a **verb** here, meaning "to mine" or "to extract resources from the ground".

The sentence can be simplified to:

> When you are away from the battlefield, you can send your troops to safe areas, **while** **looking for gold** and upgrading your equipment.

Structurally, it's identical to:

> When you are working in Canada, you can send money home, **while enjoying** the scenery and learning French.

Here is one more detail to notice:

The way the example sentence is constructed, the *subject* of "mining" is **"you", not the troops.**

You can rewrite the example sentence as:

> When you are away from the battlefield, you can send your troops to safe areas, while **you are** looking for gold and upgrading **your** equipment.

but not:

> When you are away from the battlefield, you can send your troops to safe areas, while **they look** for gold and upgrading **their** equipment.

Answer (score 1):

From your link, 'mine' as a verb can mean:

2a : to get (something, such as ore) from the earth

b : to extract from a source

It is this sense which is meant here: you (or your soldiers) can extract resources from somewhere.